# SELECT dentro de un CURSOR

Tags: sql-server, cursor

Tengo el siguiente cursor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea es consultar un listado de "Demandas", lo interesante es que algunas son creadas por los usuarios y otras de manera automática por el sistema, dentro del listado se quiere saber cuáles son creadas por usuario y cuales por el sistema.

El cursor funciona correctamente al ejecutarlo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sin embargo, al momento de leer la consulta desde mi CODE BESIDE el listado únicamente contiene un resultado, Demandad = 3.

Me queda claro que desde SQL SERVER los resultados de la consulta se están mostrando por separado, seguramente por como invoco el SELECT dentro del CURSOR, entonces la pregunta es

¿Qué puedo hacer para que dichos resultados no sean arrojados de forma separada y así leer mi lista completa?

Comment: Hola Ivan. Por favor incluye el código SQL en texto, no con una imagen. Gracias.

Comment: Ok, de acuerdo.

Answer (score 0):

Me adhiero al pedido que pegues el Script en texto y no un bitmap. De todas formas te hago los siguientes comentarios:

- Tenés un problema con las variables, estás se actualizarán cuando se da determinada condición, si luego no se vuelve a dar la variables seguirán "arrastrando" los valores anteriores, en todo caso habría que agregar un ELSE y asignarles NULL o ''.
- Tu pregunta puntual era si se podía devolver un único "resultset", de la forma en que está armado el Script no, eventualmente lo que podrías hacer es reemplazar el SELECT dentro de un cursor por un INSERT en una tabla temporal para ir acumulando todos los resultados, y afuera del cursor haces un SELECT final pero de la tabla temporal.
- Ahora, lo más importante **¿Por qué un cursor?**, por lo que ví tranquilamente se puede resolver la lógica con un único SELECT a DemandaAlmacen con un LEFT JOIN a USUARIO.

Saludos..

Comment: Saludos Patricio: de antemano agradezco muchísimo tus observaciones, si efectivamente lo que quiero hacer es retornar todo en un único "Resulset"...  Con respecto al CURSOR, para serte bien honesto apenas estoy considerando opciones para resolverlo, intentare con el LEFT JOIN, no se me había ocurrido.

Answer (score 0):

Al final la solución fue tan simple como lo propuso Patricio Moracho, un lEFT JOIN fue suficiente.

> SELECT DemandaAlmacen.*, DemandaTipo.DemandaTipoNombre, 
>   ISNULL(Usuario.UsuarioNoEmpleado, '0') AS NoEmpleado,
>   ISNULL(Usuario.UsuarioNombre,'Este folio fue creado automáticamente
>   por el sistema.') AS Nombre, ISNULL(Usuario.UsuarioApPaterno,'') AS
>   ApPaterno,ISNULL(Usuario.UsuarioApMaterno,'') AS ApMaterno FROM
>   DemandaAlmacen INNER JOIN DemandaTipo  ON DemandaAlmacen.DemandaTipoId
>   = DemandaTipo.DemandaTipoId  LEFT JOIN Usuario ON DemandaAlmacen.UsuarioId = Usuario.UsuarioId WHERE
>   DemandaAlmacen.SucursalId = 2